# PHP Session is not read

Tags: php, linux, session

I'm having some "fun" sharing session between magento and Symfony2. It works really well on my computer (mac osx 10.6 + PHP 5.3.3) and here is the mechanism :

- User logs in into magento (on foo.example.com)
- User goes on another website (bar.example.com) and is logged as well.
- Session are stored as files under the magento var/session directory.

The session cookie is set to be shared on all .example.com subdomains.
As I said before, it works perfectly on my machine.

I deployed the two applications today on an Ubuntu 8.0.4 server with PHP 5.3.5-dotdeb and configured the session sharing mechanism for my production domains (.example.org).
The session cookie is shared between the two subdomains as well.

And now, the fun begins :

- I log in on my magento application on foo.example.org and gets a session cookie with value "abc"
- A file name sess_abc is create in magento var/session directory.
- file owner is www-data:www-data and files rights are -rw-------
- If I refresh the magento page, I'm still logged.
- I go to my other application on bar.example.org
- PHP accepts the session cookie abc but does NOT retrieve the data inside.
- If I do a var_dump($_SESSION), I'll have an empty array
- At the end, the file sess_abc is overwritten and the rights are the same.
- If I refresh this page, my var_dump will provide some informations that symfony wrote into the session.

Do you guys have any thought on why PHP does not retrieve datas from this session file ?
I already tried to chmod go+rw the session file but the result is the same...

A big big big thanx in advance !

EDIT :

Suhosin is enabled.
phpinfo() gives this on bar.example.org

```
suhosin.session.checkraddr  0   0
suhosin.session.cryptdocroot    On  On
suhosin.session.cryptkey    [ protected ]   [ protected ]
suhosin.session.cryptraddr  0   0
suhosin.session.cryptua Off Off
suhosin.session.encrypt On  On
suhosin.session.max_id_length   128 128
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   no value    nocache
session.cookie_domain   .example.org    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 3600    0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    frontend    PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /www/var/session    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: In your `php.ini`, what is `session.cookie_domain` set to?

Comment: A stab in the dark: is `suhosin` enabled on your host, and if so, what are its `suhosin.session.*` settings? (and please provide all normal `session.*` settings as well, saves more guesswork :)

Comment: @futurecat: `session.cookie_domain` looks good, so my idea is busted.

Comment: @Wrikken : I disabled suhosin extension and it works like a charm. I'm gonna disable the settings that wrack off the app and enable suhosing again. Anyway, I owe you a beer! ;) Thanx

Comment: Ack, the `suhosin.session.cryptdocroot` is the one that does it I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you you know, but magento store sessions in "private" folder `path/to/magento/var/session`... May be on MacOS you could overide your php.ini (trought magento) in oder to overide your session path; But on ubuntu you cannot (/may not) overide you php.ini...

Have you check this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is sushosin and configuration "suhosin.session.cryptdocroot" and maybe "suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot". You must turn off this values. With this values On, soshosin crypt session with DocumnetRoot value.

Set this in your sushosin config (suhosin.ini in Ubuntu):

```
suhosin.session.cryptdocroot = off
suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot = off
```

For more details look at [here](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.session.cryptdocroot)